# Can't add .sppkg solution to site

Tags: sharepoint-online, solution-deployment, deploy

I have some troubles with deploying .sppkg solution. I tried to add somehow application to my site but i can't deploy it even in developer site. I tried to add this app to AppCataloge in admin site, but add button doesn't exist (I am an admin). I can debug project using local/hosted workbench.

I can't even drag/drop files:
[image: Sharepoint App Catalog]

When i try to deploy an app in developer site, I have this error:
[image: manifest files]

---

The problem, why I couldn't add apps was related to Site Collection. I found in my site collections list -> [https://mypage.sharepoint.com/sites/App_Catalog](https://%3Cname%3E.sharepoint.com/sites/App_Catalog) -> and I added my account to admins of this page.

@jussi-palo - I apologize for that I could misdirect you (I thought that sharepoint admin is also an admin of App_Catalog)

But still I can't add any apps through Dev site (and Extension-type apps are always invalid).

[image]

Comment: Please open Service Request with Microsoft, there might be something wrong with the tenant farm.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the line may help you:

> This does not seem to be a supported use case at the moment. It is
>   possible with SharePoint Add-Ins, but not SPFx WebParts.

You can find the complete thread [Deployment to Developer Site is not possible](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/537)